# Building a custom loss function to solve a ordinary differntial equation of nth order

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, math, deep-learning

I am trying to build a RNN model to solve nth order ODE i have constructed a basic design but i am not getting the desired O/P graph which matches with the actual solution
I figured out this was most likely due to incorrect loss function utilisation in this case.I tried But i was unable to build a custom loss function .

The code is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras

# Step 1: Generate training data
N = 40
E = 0.01

x_train = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
y_train = 6 * x_train**3 * E * (1 - x_train)**5

# Step 2: Train the ANN
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0)

# Step 3: Approximate the solution
x_pred = np.linspace(0.1,0.9, 1000)
y_pred = model.predict(x_pred)

# Calculate absolute error
y_actual = 6 * x_pred**3 * E * (1 - x_pred)**5
absolute_error = np.abs(y_actual - y_pred.flatten())

# Step 4: Plot the numerical solution
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(x_train, y_train, 'bo', label='Training Data')
plt.plot(x_pred, y_pred, 'r-', label='Numerical Solution')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y(x)')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(x_pred, absolute_error, 'g-', label='Absolute Error')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Absolute Error')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[the closest solution i was able to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTJBA.png)

I'm looking for explanation and code to build a custom loss function such that: loss function that penalizes deviations from satisfying the ODE and the initial condition. In this example, the loss function is a weighted sum of the ODE loss and the initial condition loss.